# Comment on fitness of multi linear model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model, fitting, diagnostic

I have a dataset which I ran the `lm()` below.

```
fit <- lm(a~x+y+z,data = data)
summary(fit)
Call:
lm(formula = a ~ x + y + z, data = mdata)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-100431   -1321    -829      70   51321 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   5157.4      585.8   8.558  < 2e-16 ***
x      -30094.2     6747.0  -4.460 8.37e-06 ***
y        2206.1     7911.7   0.307     0.81    
z      -84537.2    10476.1  -8.031 1.11e-15 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3866 on 4718 degrees of freedom
  (852 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.02072,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02001 
F-statistic: 32.84 on 3 and 4718 DF,  p-value: < 2.1e-16
```

I think that the next improvement step would be to add more variables (high significance but low $R^2$) and to remove variable y. However, I still concerned about model fit.
Can you guys help with the intepretation? My guess was "pretty okay" in terms of fit. See below the regression diagnostics.

```
plot(fit)
```

[image: regression diagnostics]

Comment: "Pretty okay"? We cannot tell what that might mean, since you haven't explained what these data represent or how these results might be used.  One can't help noticing, though, that the sizes of many residuals are in the tens of thousands while the fitted values are only in the thousands: that looks pretty awful.

Comment: That Q-Q plot doesn't look okay at all.

Comment: @whuber x,y,z are explanatory variables for annual net income (a) of set of companies. x,y,z are each probabilities (i.e. any value within [0,1]) - I guess that's part of the reason why the values are so high... :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you look at the normal Q-Q plot, which sorts your residuals from the lowest (should be negative) to the highest and fits them into normal quantiles??

Carlos, here you may see the tails (leftmost and rightmost) are more extreme than the normal distribution should be (we say heavy-tails), meaning that the model violates the normal assumption.

From the residual-fitted plot, it is possible to say that the residuals are non-constant (heteroscedasticity).

So, I suggest you, if you are interested in diagnostics, to try also

$\bullet$ half-norm plot (check high leverage point)

$\bullet$ Bonferroni correction (check outliers)